# Can participants represent our end users for large SAAS applications? What are the limits?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, saas, hyperledger-composer

In our application, we can have a lot of users. (10000 ++)
We would like to give our users the opportunity to sign their transactions, list their assets, in a private environment.
They have their own end users and assets, and will be able to manage them through the network.

At first, our users would use our network, and then we hope to be able to offer them a higher level of privacy by allowing them to interact with their own network. (via the ledger)

We have built a system using composer where our end users (our customers) have their own identities. But we need to be sure we will not have any limitations. Knowing that with this scheme, the number of participants can become huge and the management of identities could become a nightmare

We searched, but we did not find information related to the limitations of such a system built with hyperledger composer.

We understand that a business network is private, but in the case of a SAAS application what would be your recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it sounds like you want to give organisations access to a SaaS application and (ultimately) maintain separation (privacy) of the ledger - for an individual organisation (and its users).

You can deploy the SAME business network (smart contract and deployed business model) on separate channels (as in Fabric channels) so then each organisation will have its own ledger. Furthermore, you as the SaaS provider can either issue identities from a central CA registrar in the SaaS network - or - more likely - each has access to their own CA to issue identities (ie certificates) - however that's configured - so that their users can sign transactions (eg from the application).

Those users would connect to their business network (and access that ledger) via business network cards - the 'card' contains the identity information and connection metadata to connect to the deployed business network (from the application in question, eg via the APIs). After an end-user signs in, a check can be made to see if they have a busness network card, to be able to interact with the ledger.

Its likely that the SaaS provider or individual organisations would (through some UI or management capability) issue the cards and have them persisted/stored centrally/securely - ie so the SaaS application running in the end-user's browser(say) can access the user's wallet in that org, which contains the business network card and identity info - just one possible implementation example).

The building of / issuing of cards can be automated (as can the creation of a participant in Composer - which maps to an identity). A CA server will issue a certificate for each identity registered, and each unique identity would therefore have a unique business card (miniscule footprint ie < 1k). Does that help ? So I don't see a major 'limitation', nor a major overhead in what you propose.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this confirms that our understanding of the system is correct. What you offer to create identities and generate cards is exactly what we do.

Comment: I need a final clarification, when you talk about a central point for storing cards, for now we use mongodb to store the cards issued and that our customers can communicate with the rest api.
I still have a little trouble understanding where the identities (not the cards) are stored in the ledger, and why we can not delete them, can you please clarify this point?
If a user loses their card, we understand that we can recover it from mongodb, but if mongodb crashes and loses its data, are we able to recreate those cards from existing identities?
Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Sure, mongodb as the store and access via REST is fine. The identities are stored in an Identity Registry (mapping of a named id (eg joe) with a certificate as issued by Fabric). The id in Composer is mapped to a participant in Composer (a participant can have one or more ids and therefore certs just clarifying). Certs (and therefore ids in Composer) can be revoked (so you revoke the cert). To provide another, you issue another identity (cert) provided by the CA server. The user will get a card with that id - that's it.

Comment: And finally, yes, you would be able to recreate the cards, as the ids are stored as part of the business network (from which to recreate any lost cards). As you know, in practical terms, you would probably maintain a backup of the cards too.

Comment: Your clarifications are perfect and I am now comfortable with the concept.
Thank you very much !